# Can I get iPhone charge status from my Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac

I have my iPhone plugged into my Mac via USB. Is there anyway to check on the charge status? I know iTunes does give you a small battery indicator, but I am looking for something a bit more detailed, like % charge.

I thought it is something nice to have and I am a bit lazy to reach for my iPhone to check every time I charge my phone.

Comment: May or may not be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453344/how-do-you-get-the-charge-status-of-a-connected-iphone-from-the-mac

Comment: Good point. But getting MFI is a bit troublesome...

Comment: Yes, I'd agree it'd be a tad more work than reaching for your iPhone every so often. :-)

Comment: Exactly! I am just a lazy bum :)

Comment: Which can be good sometimes-- how else do you think we got labor-saving devices? :)

Comment: I guess it's because someone is a little bit more hardworking than me

Comment: But someone had to have that laziness in the first place to want a labor-saving device. :)

Comment: I you are lazy to look for the phone, you will definitely not want to implement this yourself, especially considering that this would require you to use undocumented APIs or even jailbreaking the phone. Do you want to spend few weeks doing this? I doubt.

Comment: Did I say I want to implement it? I was looking for a ready solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to see the charge status on the iPhone page on the new iTunes 11.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really quite janky, but one option may be to install [Reflection](http://www.reflectionapp.com/), have the iPhone set to mirror to Reflection, and call it a day.  You're going to want to use a charge cable here since this drains the battery right quick.

It doesn't currently support this use-case, but the [Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123) does have a monitoring section that probably will support battery-level monitoring at some point.

Really though?  I'd get [iStat for iPhone](http://bjango.com/iphone/istat/) and set up the device on a dock.  It's got a nice big battery monitor.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The answer works, I've done it before...

Comment: Sadly, this is the best choice we have to get a percentage. It's quite inventive and would be bonus worthy if there were a way to have just the battery percentage area cropped to show the status.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to get this information as you get a % charged figure for the iPhone when you plug it into a machine running Linux.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I believe the question asked is more focused on getting examples on how this could be used on Mac rather than "Is this possible?" which your answer only partially covers without any facts to backing it up. I hope this clarifies for you.

Comment: You can use an application called "Coconut Battery" to see the iPhone current charge status in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it using this app I think: https://www.fadel.io/batteries (mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375363/can-i-check-iphone-ipad-watch-battery-on-mac)).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/316593)

Answer (score -2):

The answer is no.  See, the battery in your phone is connected to the "motherboard" of your iphone. Think of it as the battery is only working for the iphone.

When you plug your phone in via USB, you can't access the information about the battery from your computer because of this.

Comment: This is clearly wrong, since iTunes is able to display the battery charge level.

Comment: My apologies, I thought the OP was asking about a % charged number.  As far as I know, that is not available.