# Can I check iPhone, iPad, Watch battery on Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, software-recommendation, battery

My goal is to have battery status of other Apple device on my Mac (preferably on menubar). I'd like to have a glimpse of the battery status of my iPhone, iPad, Watch, and Airpods.

I'm a user of Bitbar and iStat menu, but I haven't found any widgets can wirelessly check other Apple device's battery status.

What I know is that I can click the Wi-Fi icon on menu bar and it will show my iPhone battery status. To show the percentage, I have to <kbd>option</kbd> + click the Wi-Fi icon and hover over my mouse on the iPhone hot spot section. It's pretty clunky, but I guess at least the API is there.

I am also open to third party apps which can let me see battery status across devices.

Answer (score 10):

Any mac will come preinstalled with an application called "Find My"
You can see the battery level and location for all your Apple devices here.

I realise it's not in the toolbar, but you can use it regardless of whether your iPhone is nearby (I use it to check my phone level when I am working upstairs, and my phone is in my room charging).

Answer (score 4):

I've found [Batteries for Mac](https://fadel.io/batteries), which tracks the battery level of iPhone/iPad and AirPods (amongst others) wirelessly. It also has low battery notifications.
It's a paid app though.

Answer (score 2):

**[This is not a final answer as long as this line exists]**

Assumptions I am making:

- I am assuming you are on the latest version iOS and macOS.
- You have the same account logged into the iPhone as well as Mac.

Even if you keep personal hotspot toggled off — unless you’re sharing your cellular connection with someone else — the latest versions of iOS and macOS still see available hotspots from devices with the same iCloud accounts enabled as part of Apple’s Continuity feature.

### Here is how to see the Battery Percentage of your iPhone on a macOS system:

1. Make sure you have same iCloud account logged into iPhone and macOS device.
2. Turn on Wi-Fi from macOS.
3. Then click on the Wi-Fi icon on the menubar and wait for your iPhone to appear on the list. You can now see the graphical indicator of your iPhone’s battery level.
4. But if you want to know the *precise* percentage of your battery level follow further steps.
5. Hold on <kbd>option</kbd> key.
6. Then click on the Wi-Fi icon on the menubar.
7. This time when your hover pointer over the device, you should be able to see the battery percentage of iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

[CoconutBattery](https://coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) & [Battery Health](https://fiplab.com/apps/battery-health-3-for-mac) both claim that they can do that, you should try them out as they both have a free trial ! (I believe that the WIFI feature in coconut battery is only available with the prenium app)

*"With coconutBattery you are always aware of your current battery health. It shows you live information about the battery quality in your Mac, iPhone and iPad"* - CoconutBattery

*"You can use Battery Health to connect to your iPhone or iPad over WiFi Sync or USB cable to retrieve useful iOS battery data. [...] Newly added to Battery Health is the ability to easily check the battery level of bluetooth devices such as your Apple Magic Keyboard, Mouse, Trackpad and AirPods. Use it to keep an eye on your batteries and replace/recharge them before they run out."* - Battery Health

Answer (score 0):

I found this application [Battery Widget 2.0](https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/battery-widget-2-0/id1561658854) and a [review](https://macsources.com/battery-widget-2-review/) for it.

With this app, you can check your battery percentage on your watch, iPhone, Mac, or iPad. This feature was important for me.